# How do I call other functions from the message loop of a VCL project?

Tags: c++, api, c++builder

I have project where I need to use an API which comes with a dll and .cpp as well as .h files.
In the documentation I am told to use the PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) class function of the provided API and place it into the message loop of the User Interface.

Is it possible to use C++ Builder as the IDE for this project, and if yes, then how, as it doesn't have a message loop where I could place this function.

Comment: I don't remember how, but it is possible to use C++Builder with the `VCL` to post messages in the message queue by `PreTranslateMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VCL app in C++Builder **does** have a message loop (it is a normal Windows app, after all).  It is tucked away inside the `TApplication::Run()` method, which is called inside the project's `WinMain()` function.  If you want to call `PreTranslateMessage()` inside this loop, you can assign an event handler to the `TApplication::OnMessage` event, either directly or via the `TApplicationEvents` component.  The `OnMessage` event is triggered immediately after a message is removed from the message queue before the VCL processes it.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this out](http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/Lesson06.htm), it has some documentation about the process of integrating Windows Event messages with the [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library), althougth don't know if that applies for your project, in case that your project uses the `MFC` framework, you are better with Visual Studio.

In either case, you can include `windows.h` and have access to the `win32` API functions

Comment: no, my project isn't tight to MFC. As a matter of fact I am looking for a way to avoid it. I am just in search of a nice IDE where I could both create a nice GUI and be able to code the project in C AND put the PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) where it is supposed to be, in the application's message loop.